# ¿Es normal que un proceso Apache use el 50% de CPU?

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

**CONTEXTO.** Apache 2.4 en Linux.

**QUÉ ESTOY VIENDO.**
Como se ve en la siguiente captura de pantalla, [HTOP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) muestra un listado de procesos actuales, y me dice que existe un proceso httpd con un uso de CPU de 50.2%, pero un segundo después desaparece ese proceso de la lista, lo que implica (supongo) que ese proceso quizá sigue existiendo, pero ha dejado de usar 50.2% de CPU, porque ya no aparece en la parte alta de la lista , la cual está ordenada por la columna CPU.
[image: HTOP - Listado de procesos]

**DUDAS.**

1. Mi servidor disponde de 24 cpus/núcleos. La primera pregunta es: ¿50.2% de qué? ¿Es el 50.2% de un único cpu/núcleo, o de todos los núcleos?
2. ¿Es normal que un proceso httpd alcance un 50.2% de uso de CPU?
3. ¿Cómo debo entender que un proceso httpd use 50.2% de CPU y otro proceso httpd distinto use 35.4, y distintos porcentajes para otros procesos httpd?
4. Entiendo que los procesos httpd **no** representan cada uno un visitante del sitio web, más bien estos procesos en su conjunto son los que se hacen cargo de las peticiones al servidor, es decir, de los visitantes que entran al sitio web. Si esto es correcto, ¿ese proceso httpd de 50.2% de uso de CPU significa que el total de visitantes del sitio web están usando ese porcentaje de mi CPU?

Por favor, siéntanse libres de corregir cualquier cosa que haya escrito y falte a la verdad.
Saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si, un proceso podría llegar a marcar 50% (o más) y los otros procesos podrían tener valores más pequeños. Una forma de explicarlo (más no la única) es si llegó una petición que le toma mucho tiempo de CPU y las demás peticiones son de respuestas rápidas. Ese proceso que se está ocupando de esa única petición va a tener una carga mayor a todos los demás procesos... y es normal.

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente alguien le saque tiempo a una respuesta más extensa. Por ahora:

1. El porcentaje hace referencia al tiempo de CPU disponible, sean 1, 2, 48 núcleos o como sea. Deendiendo de la arquitectura, el tiempo de CPU disponible varía.
2. *Puede* ser normal dependiendo del uso! Si tuviéramos una cámara que mostrara un momento muy pequeño, una foto del uso de CPU, posiblemente un par de procesos estarían con un porcentaje muy muy alto o un solo proceso tendría el 100% en el caso de un solo núcleo. Tampoco sabemos la concurrencia sobre tu sitio ni los módulos que le has añadido, si está haciendo algún ejercicio de encripción o algo intensivo en uso de CPU.
3. Los porcentajes van sobre los tiempos de CPU disponibles pero, PEEEERO, los sistemas *nix tienen una forma particular de hablar del tiempo de CPU usado. Si miras la imagen que nos compartes, hay un proceso con más del 100% (y no preguntaste nada al respecto). Si fuese un porcentaje sobre la CPU disponible en un instante del tiempo, no tiene sentido que haya alguien usando el 302% (la CPU no puede dar el FUAAAA). En esos valores, el OS también está diciendo que al proceso *se le debe* tiempo de CPU que ha pedido y se ha quedado esperando. Mira arriba a la derecha esos valores para *Load average* que dicen 0.84 0.77 0.64. Dicen que en el último 1 minuto, 5 minutos y 15 minutos, tu equipo ha estado cargado al 84%, 77% y 64% del tiempo disponible (y el restante ha estado en estado *idle* la CPU).
4. Cada programa levanta los hilos que requiera para su funcionamiento. De nuevo, sin más detalles, no tienes cómo saber si ese hilo del proceso httpd está escribiendo un log, creando un archivo de log nuevo porque está rotando, encriptando un archivo pa enviarlo por la conexión https, etc. Lo que sí puedes concluir es que, dado el uso que le daban los usuarios a tu servidor HTTP, el servicio httpd está usando ese tiempo de CPU **en ese instante de tiempo**. Ese número sin contexto no dice nada. Si haces una prueba de carga, hazla con una herramienta que te permita identificar demoras o comportamientos extraños en las peticiones que le haces al servidor.

Comment: Bastante buena la respuesta, pero algunos comentarios: un solo proceso puede marcar mas de 100% y ello no implica que se ha quedado esperando. En caso de ser un proceso multihilos, puede haber mas de un hilo ejecutándose en un momento dado (de un solo proceso) y ese tiempo podría entonces superar el 100%.

Comment: Otro punto es sobre la carga. La _unidad_ para representar carga puede ser o bien un proceso que está ejecutándose en CPU ocupando el tiempo disponible, o es un proceso que está listo para ejecutarse y esperando que lo pongan a correr en un CPU (cosa que quieres evitar y por eso le metes más CPUs).... **o** (esta es menos conocida) un proceso está _no está listo para correr_ en espera de algún tipo (normalmente, IO). Si un procesador tiene 48 CPUs, entonces podrías tener una carga de hasta 48 (asumiendo que los procesos están en ejecución, no en espera de IO) y estarías _bien_.

Comment: Importantes aclaraciones. Gracias! @eftshift0